# Why is Visual C++ Installer necessary to install numpy package for Python?

Tags: python, c++, windows, numpy, installation

Just as the question states, I'm interested in the WHY. What exactly is happening that the numpy package cannot be installed without it?

Comment: Without _what_? Python - because numpy is a Python module. C++ - because it's partly written in C++.

Comment: @ForceBru without C++, as the title suggests. And thanks.

Comment: Which "Visual C++ installer" exactly? Do you mean the C++ runtime libraries?

Comment: I think you need to add some kind of windows tag.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks, I did that!

Comment: @BogdanWilli, In order to run pip install numpy, I was required to download Visual C++ 9.0, according to the error message. I hadn't come across this situation before, so I was curious what was so different about numpy from other packages.

Comment: For the nitpicky record, there is no C++ in numpy, just C. It's just that Visual C++ is the primary C compiler on Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two main things you need to know:

- Python packages are usually distributed as sources (though there's an ongoing effort to ship them as binary wheels instead).
- Python packages sometimes include C or C++ code. That's the case for Numpy (but a lot of other packages don't).

But, when you install a package from source, and it includes C or C++ code, you need to compile that code to run it (unlike Python code, which is interpreted).

But, to compile C / C++ code, you need a C / C++ compiler. As it turns out, Visual C++ ships with a C / C++ compiler (and it's the standard for Windows).

---

Note that if you were using Linux instead of Windows, you'd want to install `gcc` (or `clang`) instead.

Comment: Thank you for that reply; concise and clear! Do you know what the advantage to shipping them as binary wheels is? I'll accept your answer once time permits.

Comment: @codycrossley Binary releases don't require end users to have a compiler, and are faster to install (because you don't need to compile them). This isn't specific to Python though — searching for "binary vs source release" should bring up plenty of useful information!