# Pycharm: problem for installing and/or using packages

Tags: python, pip, package, pycharm, libraries

I'm relatively new to python and even more to PyCharm. I have trouble using and installing libraries on PyCharm, so I will break down the problem in two. For info, I'm on windows 10 and using Python 3.9.

**Using libraries**

I have successfully installed several packages and libraries via pip, and I'm able use them without a problem using VS as IDE for instance. However when I code with PyCharm (which I want to..) it doesn't recognize the classes and method of these libraries. After searching I found out that if my project is create via a virtual environment, I will need to either:

1. download the library individually for each project
2. Or create project with the option "Inherit global site-packages" (see the picture). [image]

The first option is described below. For the second I did so, but nothing changes... the packages seems to be unknown to PyCharm

**Downloading libraries**

First of, again, the libraries are install and I reinstalled with pip vi cmd but it states that it is there already:

```
C:\>pip install -U scikit-learn
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in c:\users\antdu953\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.3 in c:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.23.2)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.5.0 in c:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.9.3)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=1.1.1 in c:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in c:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn) (3.1.0)
```

In my script, Pycharm suggest the installation of the package (see figure) , so I tried this way and here is the error:
[image]

```
Collecting scikit-learn
  Using cached scikit-learn-1.3.0.tar.gz (7.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [110 lines of output]
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.10" and platform_system == "Windows" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"' don't match your environment
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached setuptools-68.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (804 kB)
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.40.0-py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
  Collecting Cython>=0.29.33
    Using cached Cython-0.29.36-py2.py3-none-any.whl (988 kB)
  Collecting oldest-supported-numpy
    Using cached oldest_supported_numpy-2022.11.19-py3-none-any.whl (4.9 kB)
  Collecting scipy>=1.5.0
    Using cached scipy-1.11.1.tar.gz (56.0 MB)
    Installing build dependencies: started
    Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
    pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
    exit code: 1
  
    [80 lines of output]
    Ignoring numpy: markers 'platform_machine == "loongarch64"' don't match your environment
    Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.10" and platform_system == "Windows" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"' don't match your environment
    Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.9" and (platform_system != "Windows" and platform_machine != "loongarch64") and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"' don't match your environment
    Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.10" and (platform_system != "Windows" and platform_machine != "loongarch64") and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"' don't match your environment
    Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.11" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"' don't match your environment
    Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.12"' don't match your environment
    Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.9" and platform_python_implementation == "PyPy"' don't match your environment
    Collecting meson-python<0.14.0,>=0.12.1
      Using cached meson_python-0.13.2-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
    Collecting Cython<3.0,>=0.29.35
      Using cached Cython-0.29.36-py2.py3-none-any.whl (988 kB)
    Collecting pybind11<2.11.0,>=2.10.4
      Using cached pybind11-2.10.4-py3-none-any.whl (222 kB)
    Collecting pythran<0.14.0,>=0.12.0
      Using cached pythran-0.13.1-py3-none-any.whl (4.3 MB)
    Collecting wheel<0.41.0
      Using cached wheel-0.40.0-py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
    Collecting numpy==1.22.3
      Using cached numpy-1.22.3.zip (11.5 MB)
      Installing build dependencies: started
      Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
      Getting requirements to build wheel: started
      Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
      Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
      exit code: 1
  
      [40 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\antdu953\WAVE ENERGY\RESEARCH\MODELLING\DATADRIVEN\test\venv\lib\python3.9\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\antdu953\WAVE ENERGY\RESEARCH\MODELLING\DATADRIVEN\test\venv\lib\python3.9\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\Users\antdu953\WAVE ENERGY\RESEARCH\MODELLING\DATADRIVEN\test\venv\lib\python3.9\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 112, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          backend = _build_backend()
        File "C:\Users\antdu953\WAVE ENERGY\RESEARCH\MODELLING\DATADRIVEN\test\venv\lib\python3.9\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 77, in _build_backend
          obj = import_module(mod_path)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
          return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-mjd6kays\overlay\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 242, in <module>
          monkey.patch_all()
        File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-mjd6kays\overlay\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 99, in patch_all
          patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler()
        File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-mjd6kays\overlay\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 162, in patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler
          patch_func(*msvc9('find_vcvarsall'))
        File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-mjd6kays\overlay\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 149, in patch_params
          mod = import_module(mod_name)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
          return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-mjd6kays\overlay\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 295, in <module>
          raise DistutilsPlatformError("VC %0.1f is not supported by this module" % VERSION)
      distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: VC 6.0 is not supported by this module
      [end of output]
  
      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
    Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
    exit code: 1
  
    See above for output.
  
    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
    [end of output]
  
    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
exit code: 1

See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

From this error PyCharm recommend me the following:

```
C:\Users\antdu953\WAVE ENERGY\RESEARCH\MODELLING\DATADRIVEN\test\venv\bin\activate.bat
pip install scikit-learn
```

I do so and find another error that seems similar to the one obtain before.

```
Collecting scikit-learn
  Using cached scikit-learn-1.3.0.tar.gz (7.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [110 lines of output]
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.10" and platform_system == "Windows" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"' don't match your environment
      Collecting setuptools
        Using cached setuptools-68.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (804 kB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.40.0-py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
      Collecting Cython>=0.29.33
        Using cached Cython-0.29.36-py2.py3-none-any.whl (988 kB)
      Collecting oldest-supported-numpy
        Using cached oldest_supported_numpy-2022.11.19-py3-none-any.whl (4.9 kB)
      Collecting scipy>=1.5.0
        Using cached scipy-1.11.1.tar.gz (56.0 MB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1

        [80 lines of output]
        Ignoring numpy: markers 'platform_machine == "loongarch64"' don't match your environment
        Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.10" and platform_system == "Windows" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"' don't match your environment
        Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.9" and (platform_system != "Windows" and platform_machine != "loongarch64") and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"' don't match your environment
        Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.10" and (platform_system != "Windows" and platform_machine != "loongarch64") and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"' don't match your environment
        Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.11" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"' don't match your environment
        Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.12"' don't match your environment
        Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.9" and platform_python_implementation == "PyPy"' don't match your environment
        Collecting meson-python<0.14.0,>=0.12.1
          Using cached meson_python-0.13.2-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
        Collecting Cython<3.0,>=0.29.35
          Using cached Cython-0.29.36-py2.py3-none-any.whl (988 kB)
        Collecting pybind11<2.11.0,>=2.10.4
          Using cached pybind11-2.10.4-py3-none-any.whl (222 kB)
        Collecting pythran<0.14.0,>=0.12.0
          Using cached pythran-0.13.1-py3-none-any.whl (4.3 MB)
        Collecting wheel<0.41.0
          Using cached wheel-0.40.0-py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
        Collecting numpy==1.22.3
          Using cached numpy-1.22.3.zip (11.5 MB)
          Installing build dependencies: started
          Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
          Getting requirements to build wheel: started
          Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
          error: subprocess-exited-with-error

          Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
          exit code: 1

          [40 lines of output]
          Traceback (most recent call last):
            File "C:\Users\antdu953\WAVE ENERGY\RESEARCH\MODELLING\DATADRIVEN\test\venv\lib\python3.9\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
              main()
            File "C:\Users\antdu953\WAVE ENERGY\RESEARCH\MODELLING\DATADRIVEN\test\venv\lib\python3.9\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
              json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
            File "C:\Users\antdu953\WAVE ENERGY\RESEARCH\MODELLING\DATADRIVEN\test\venv\lib\python3.9\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 112, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
              backend = _build_backend()
            File "C:\Users\antdu953\WAVE ENERGY\RESEARCH\MODELLING\DATADRIVEN\test\venv\lib\python3.9\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 77, in _build_backend
              obj = import_module(mod_path)
            File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
              return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
            File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
            File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
            File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
            File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
            File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
            File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
            File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
            File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
            File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
            File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
            File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-2l_eu66c\overlay\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 242, in <module>
              monkey.patch_all()
            File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-2l_eu66c\overlay\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 99, in patch_all
              patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler()
            File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-2l_eu66c\overlay\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 162, in patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler
              patch_func(*msvc9('find_vcvarsall'))
            File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-2l_eu66c\overlay\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 149, in patch_params
              mod = import_module(mod_name)
            File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
              return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
            File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
            File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
            File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
            File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
            File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
            File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
            File "C:\Users\antdu953\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-2l_eu66c\overlay\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 295, in <module>
              raise DistutilsPlatformError("VC %0.1f is not supported by this module" % VERSION)
          distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: VC 6.0 is not supported by this module
          [end of output]

          note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1

        See above for output.

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error

      pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
      exit code: 1

      See above for output.

      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

So nothing seems to work and I don't seem to understand why...I also tried installing directly from PyCharm python package management.

I know there are topics about these issues already, but none seems to help so far.. Thanks for your help !

Comment: In your original `C:\>pip install` where did you run that from? It's probable that that wasn't in your venv.

Comment: @Reinderien thanks for your message !
I have created a new project on my desktop and here's what I did:
`C:\Users\antdu953\Desktop\PyTEST\venv\bin\activate.bat`

and then,
`(venv)C:\Users\antdu953\Desktop\PyTEST\venv>pip install scikit-learn`

I still get the same error.. so yes I have run the pip from the venv..

Comment: Looking at the error messages, it looks like numpy is the package that is complaining. Can you install other packages that don’t depend on numpy? If so, that might help narrow down your problem slightly, but I would have to do some more looking to figure this out.

Comment: Thanks for your messages @Cmd858. I have tried to intall numpy the same way, I got the same error (second part of the error only though `Getting requirements to build wheel ... error`.
I have tried with the built in package installer for numpy as well, didn't work...

Comment: One of the last lines in the error log refers to `msvc9compiler.py`. I think since parts of numpy are written in C/C++ it is trying to compile from source and failing since you don't have a valid compiler installed (I got this info from an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32593167/11072533)). You might be able to find a way to install the package as a binary from pip, but if that doesn't work you might have to install a C++ compiler to allow numpy to compile from source. Hope this helps.